# Using clipboard without separate tex file or sepfootnotes without making the content a footnote

Tags: clipboard

I want to use the `clipboard` package to cut and paste text in convenient places, but I do not want the text to show up when I copy it. Can this be done? Alternatively, it is like using `sepfootnotes` but the content should not be in footnotes (caveat here is that I already use sepfootnotes for things that do have to be in footnotes).

MWE (clipboard):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{clipboard}
\newclipboard{notes}
\begin{document}
\Copy{test}{This should only show up when it is pasted, not when it is copied.}
\openclipboard{notes}
This should be the first line of the document. \Paste{test} 
\end{document}
```

MWE (sepfootnotes):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{sepfootnotes}
\newfootnotes{notfoot}
\begin{document}
    \notfootnotecontent{test1}{This should not be in a footnote}
    \sepfootnotecontent{test2}{This should be in a footnote}
    First line of the document. \notfootnote{test1} \sepfootnote{test2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand, but isnt' the functionality you desire the same as that of `\newcommand{\PasteTest}{This should only show up when it is pasted, not when it is copied.}` and then using `PasteTest `?

Comment: Well that could work, but I'll need a lot of these pastes and it'd get increasingly difficult (but not impossible) to come up with adequate and readable `\newcommand`s.

Comment: Sure, but how is that different that coming up with names for the pastes? If you are thinking about the restrictions in the name of the macro, then with the `etoolbox` package you can use `\csdef{Copy Test 1}{This should only show up when it is pasted, not when it is copied.}` and `\csuse{Copy Test 1}` to "paste" the text.

Comment: That was indeed what I was thinking about. `\csdef` and `\csuse` look like the solution I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: There is no need to `\openclipboard{notes}` unless you're copying and pasting across documents. Your `notes` clipboard is already available as soon as `\newclipboard{notes}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `\clipboard` command directly. (I'm the package author.)

Syntax: `\clipboard {key} {content}`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{clipboard}
\newclipboard{notes}
\begin{document}
\clipboard{test}{This should only show up when it is pasted, not when it is copied.}
This should be the first line of the document. \Paste{test} 
\end{document}
```

[image]